# 10.9 Mail "smart mailbox" doesn't filter properly

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I have a smart mailbox setup to combine the inboxes of my 3 Gmail accounts.  It worked great in 10.8.  In Mavericks, this "smart inbox" frequently shows messages which have already been archived, and do not appear in the regular Gmail inbox within Mail.app.  This screenshot shows an example.  So Mail recognizes that the two messages are archived, yet they still show up here.  These two messages do no appear in the regular Gmail inbox within Mail.

I have already tried deleting and recreating the smart mailbox.  I show its settings below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has anyone followed up on this? Did you try rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more possible solutions.

### Reset Permissions

```
chmod -a 'everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown' ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/MailData/* ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/MailData/Signatures/*
```

This resets permissions on email related items (you can reset permissions on everything in Disk Utility).

### Remove Indexes

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope*
mdimport ~/Library/Mail
```

This second possibility gets rid of Mail's index (Mail will rebuild it upon restart) and refreshes Spotlight with your email content.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a rebuild of the mailboxes in question?

In the `Mailboxes` list select your `Inbox` and then select `Mailbox` > `Rebuild` then do the same with the `Gmail (All Mail)` mailbox.

Rebuilding the Gmail mailboxes may take some time.

I would then quit `Mail` and restart.

Comment: I've rebuilt the inbox multiple times, but haven't tried rebuilding the All Mail nor the smart mailbox. I will try.

Comment: Rebuilding did not fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Yosemite 10.10.1 and rebooting solved it.